# How to implement research paper network architecture algorithms

Tags: deep-learning

I'm struggling to implement this CNN architecture for this research paper: https://github.com/lindawangg/COVID-Net/blob/master/assets/COVIDNet_CXR.pdf. In Figure 2, the paper has a diagram that explains each of the individual layers of the network.

First question, for the PEPX module, it doesn't say specifically say what the input and output channels are, it only mentions:

> First-stage Projection: 1×1 convolutions for projecting input features to a lower dimension,

> Expansion: 1×1 convolutions for expanding features to a higher dimension that is different than that of the input features,

> Depth-wise Representation: efficient 3×3 depth-wise convolutions for learning spatial characteristics to minimize computational complexity while preserving representational capacity,

... and so on, how do I know what to put for each conv layer in the PEPX module?

Second question, how do I understand what all of the arrows are doing? For example, PEP1.1 has an arrow to PEPX1.3 and PEPX2.1, what does this mean?